# How to search based on one parameter in referencing table and sort based on the first record in referencing table referring that project record?

Tags: sql

I have two tables project and code. Codes table has reference of project table with one to many relationship from project to codes. Now my requirement is to get all the project data based on search condition on label  from codes table and order the project based on the label of only first record in codes table for that project

For eg if my project table has following data:

```
PROJECT_ID PROJECT_NAME PROJECT_TYPE
1          test1        a
2          test2        b
```

And codes table has below mentioned data where project_id is foreign key and if I am searching based on  label b then than first searching should happen on join of project and codes and record with label b will be found then order by will happen on the first mapping value of that project in codes i.e on record in codes with label d as that is the first record in codes referencing that project.

```
ID PROJECT_ID LABEL
1  1          d
2  1          b
3  1          c
4  2          a
```

Desired output

```
PROJECT_ID PROJECT_NAME PROJECT_TYPE
1          test1        a
```

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry my mistake, I have updated the output.

Comment: Where is the column label in your output , your output just get the first row from first table based on condition

Comment: It's not in the output but the projects are sorted based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select p.project_id, p.project_name, p.project_type, min(l.label) 
    from project p 
    inner join label l on p.project_id=l.project_id 
    where p.project_id in (select project_id from label where label=?) 
    group by p.project_id, p.project_name, p.project_type
    order by min(l.label)
```

depends on your DB, you will will perhaps need to make a inner select and order on outer query.